# Create simple mysql function inside Joomla DB query

Tags: mysql, joomla, joomla3.0

I'm trying to execute a simple Joomla DB query which creates a simple mysql functrion.

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$sql = "
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION hello_world()
  RETURNS TEXT
  LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
  RETURN 'Hello World';
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
";
$db->setQuery($sql);

if(!$db->query()) {
    JError::raiseWarning(500, $db->getErrorMsg());
    return;             
}
```

No matter what i try it get this:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'DELIMITER' at line 8 SQL=CREATE FUNCTION hello_world() RETURNS
>   TEXT LANGUAGE SQL BEGIN RETURN 'Hello World'; END; DELIMITER ;

I also tried to remove the delimiter but its the same.
When i execute that statement direkt inside mysql the function gets created.

What am i doing wrong?